# sendto: Destination becomes 0.0.0.0 regardless of address passed

Tags: macos, sockets

I'm writing a ping clone to practice socket programming. I'm able to send ICMP packets, but the destination address is 0.0.0.0 regardless of what I pass to `sendto`. Here is the most pertinent snip of code:

```
struct sockaddr_in dest;
memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
if (0 == inet_aton(argv[1], &dest.sin_addr)) {
  puts("could not parse address\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

ssize_t nbytes = sendto(sock, &hdr, ICMP_MINLEN, /*flags=*/0,
    (struct sockaddr*)&dest, sizeof(dest));
```

The full program is [on GitHub](https://github.com/thejohnfreeman/netutils/blob/master/ping/main.c). I'm compiling on and for Mac OS X 10.6.8, and I'm using Wireshark 1.8.4 to verify the packets.

I have verified the value of `dest.sin_addr.s_addr` with a call to `printf("%X")`, and `inet_aton` is working as expected. I have even deliberately set it to `0x08080808` (Google's name server), and it still doesn't work.

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it deliberate that you're not setting a port on the destination address?

Comment: Yes. No port is necessary for an ICMP packet. I'm starting to think the problem is that I have to build the IP header myself because I'm not using TCP or UDP.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I've spotted the problem now (in your full source on github; your snippet here looks good).  I've posted this as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one (copy-paste) bug in your full program on github:

```
struct sockaddr_in src;
memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
```

After declaring `src`, you memset `dest` again.  This means that dest's sin_addr member is now 0 so you're requesting a destination address of 0.0.0.0.

As an aside, src's `sin_port` is left uninitialised so you may sometimes get other errors if you end up requesting a local port that is already in use.

Comment: I just stumbled on it, too, after putting far too much effort into tracking it down. So embarrassing. Thanks for the help!